# Error de compilacion con ajax a peticion de base de datos

Tags: javascript, ajax, lógica

Buenas tardes después de haber escrito este código hace unas horas y haberlo utilizado varias veces es la primera vez que me pasa, usualmente mando la información con ajax y se ejecuta la instrucción en Php, pero dejando de lado eso, se sigue ejecutando mi archivo que le mande después de que me marcara error con un simple If, simplemente no encuentro el error que me pueda estar sucediendo. les adjunto este pequeño código puede que solo necesite otro punto de vista.

```
    function registrar(proveedor,telefono,email){

    cadena="proveedor=" + proveedor + 
            "&telefono=" + telefono +
            "&email=" + email;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"componentes/agregarProveedor.php",
        data:cadena,

        success:function(r){
            if(r==1){
                console.log("New provider");
                $('#tabla').load(); 

            }
            else{
                console.log("error");
                return false;
                
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Así se miraría en una ventana de borrador que tengo, también lo adjunto con la consola.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En fin, espero alguien me pueda dar su opinión al respecto, por lo tanto estaré trabajando para poder resolverlo lo mas rápido posible, que tengan una buena tarde gente.

Comment: ¿En la consola aparece algún error?, de ser así agrégalo

Comment: Así es, me marca error, pero aun así se ejecuta la instrucción que le puse, en este caso registra en mi base de datos.

Comment: Ocupamos el mensaje de error completo por favor

Comment: Acabo de editar la publicación , ahí sale el mensaje de error del if.

Comment: Agregale despues del success el "**error**" para ver cual es el error que te manda:
`error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log("Error: " + errorThrown); } `

Comment: No es un error como tal o si ?? Busca en tu php donde tienes un echo con ese mensaje

Comment: Dudo mucho que sea mi archivo de php donde se ejecuta, ya que nada manda a llamar las variables, hace la query, después lo ejecuto con PDO y nada mas.

Comment: @CesarReyna nunca eh visto un error de esa manera ahi en tu consola te muestra **New error :)** Ademas no te salta un color identificando la gravedad de dicho error